# How do I decrease the height of mat-select in angular material, not the options inside it?

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular

Have tried a solution I saw on Stack Overflow but it only decreased the height of the options inside the mat-select.

Thank you in advance.

[image: link to the image]

```
<mat-form-field *ngIf="!isLoading" appearance="fill">
    <mat-label>Sort by Type</mat-label>
    <mat-select
        panelClass="sel"
        name="selected"
        [(ngModel)]="selected"
        (selectionChange)="onChangeSelect()"
    >
        <mat-option value="">All</mat-option>
        <mat-option value="Db">Debit</mat-option>
        <mat-option value="Cr">Credit</mat-option>
    </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>
```

Comment: If you're going to mention another solution you should link to it, otherwise it's just distraction.

Comment: Please **revise your post** to explain.... It's still not clear what you mean. Reducing the height of just the select would hide part of it, no?

Comment: have added a image link..i want to reduce the mat-select.it is too big.. waiting for your response

Comment: That didn't really help since you haven't said what element you want to reduce. We can assume 'Sort by Type', but we're left to guess.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Show your boss/manager [this documentation from the angular material website](https://material.angular.io/guide/customizing-component-styles#component-host-elements):

> ## Component host elements
>
> For any Angular Material component, you can safely define custom CSS for a component's host element that affect the positioning or layout of that component, such as margin, position, top, left, transform, and z-index. You should apply such styles by defining a custom CSS class and applying that class to the component's host element.
>
> **Avoid defining custom styles that would affect the size or internal layout of the component, such as padding, height, width, or overflow. You can specify display: none to hide a component, but avoid specifying any other display value. Overriding these properties can break components in unexpected ways as the internal styles change between releases.**

You can absolutely hack it, but **when the framework you're using is telling you not to**, then trying it anyway is begging for trouble.

### [Appearance](https://material.angular.io/components/form-field/overview#form-field-appearance-variants)

You can specify the `appearance` attribute on the form field with `fill`, `standard`, or `outline` to give you slightly more control. Often `fill` makes the form field appear too tall, like you are saying, so maybe just specifying `appearance='standard'` will achieve a nicer result.

Comment: Thank you Adam.outline works for me better. really appreciate

Answer (score 0):

Late reply for future users

You should add the following code in your div

```
style="font-size: 10px"
```

click this link to view the differences
[Link to stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-yecvvl?file=src/app/form-field-appearance-example.html)

[Result image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N47Nk.png)